# When is a Taylor approximation exact?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Is there a quick way to find the answer? Obviously the Taylor approximation is exact at the point where it is centered ($\sin(x) = x$, for $x = 0$) but where else is the approximation 100% valid?

For example, what values of $x$ *exactly* satisfy the following relation
$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{5!}x^5$$

Comment: $x=0$ works again

Comment: What makes you think there are non-zero solutions to this equation?

Comment: I don't know if there are. I'm asking because I don't know…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be many as the absolute value of that expression will exceed $1$ after a short time. For the few solutions within that range, an analytical solution is probably not possible and you will need to solve it by numerical means.

If want equality everywhere to a truncated Taylor series then there is a name of the class of function that satisfies this: a polynomial.

Comment: Helpful answer. Is there any way we can show that some solutions do/don't exist?

Comment: In general, I doubt that there is any answer.  Asymptotic behaviour will frequently limit the range of solutions.  A truncated Taylor series will behave asymptotically as a power of $x$ which will often impose a limit as here.  Another simple case will be if all of the coefficients are positive.  For example, a truncated series for exponential will be strictly less than the function for all positive $x$ and hence there will be no positive solution.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help :)